# How to have a syntax highlighter in a editor in java?

Tags: java, swing, syntax-highlighting

I am making a programming IDE for my 10th Std. project. I am stuck at a point. I want to have syntax highlighting in my editor (just like in eclipse/netbeans). I have used JTextArea. Can anyone please help me with this? And i want to code it myself and not just use someone else (except java's) library.